# Side by Side error running Qt Creator

Tags: qt, windows-vista, side-by-side, crt, sxs

On Vista Ultimate (No SP), I installed Qt Creator 1.3 from Nokia, using the Windows Binary installer. When I tried running it, I got a side-by-side error saying:
"The Application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log for more detail."

The Event Viewer Logs showed:
"Activation context generation failed for "C:\Qt\qtcreator-1.3.0\bin\qtcreator.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis."

Running and sxstrace gave me a log file. I've uploaded the contents at http://cl1p.net/sxstrace/

I've figured it has something to do with different versions of DLLs and the Sxstrace system, and VC90.crt, but I don't know what to do. If it helps, the only other development tool I have installed on my PC is Dev-C++ (and MingW). I have had Visual Studio installed in the past, but its been uninstalled since. Other apps with VC90.crt manifests, like Limewire and Digsby are running fine. Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the [Visual C++ 2008 Redistribuable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en) or [Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistribuable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en).

Comment: haha...similar error while installing the SP1 package: http://yfrog.com/2dvcerrorj (screenshot)

A similar error popped up when installing the first package. However, an interesting tidbit was that windows update recommended I install a Security Update for VCredist, meaning it has detected a vcredist installed on my system.